# Why was my question edited?

Tags: discussion

[My question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/989134/how-to-fix-everspace-crashing-ubuntu) was [edited](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/989134/2) to use the unofficial spelling of the products title. The official spelling, which is what I used, is [all titlecase](https://everspace-game.com/). Why was this incorrect and seemingly pedantic edit made and what value does it add to the community?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because the user who edited didn't know the official styling of the game. The editor probably thought you were trying to emphasize the name and didn't realize it was written that way officially. Since using ALL CAPS is considered shouting and rude, they edited it out. Mistakes happen.

The simplest solution is to just roll back the edit. Click on the edit history, and then roll back to your first version.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from its [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everspace) including both online articles linked there, leaving out the capitalization is fairly common. As ALL CAPS is considered bad style for a good reason I personally support the edit and would have done the same thing *even* if I knew about the game. How about you write either

> Everspace

or:

> EVERSPACE™

If you really want the ™ one, maybe combine it with a link to https://everspace-game.com which both explains the capitalization *and* makes clear what you're even talking about. The latter is a good choice in any way – you can't expect everyone to know the game.

Comment: The game's author cannot create the WIkipedia entry, so the Wikipedia entry is an unofficial spelling and could very well be incorrect. Wikipedia here is an irrelevant third-party.

I can reasonably expect that if anyone is going to be editing my content that they know what the content is about before editing it.

Comment: @Vadi The game's author cannot create the Wikipedia entry, which is a very good thing when it comes to things like that. :) What exactly is an “incorrect” spelling in your opinion? Wikipedia shows how a fairly big and open community *chose* to spell the title, which IMO is a **much** better source than the author's choice. When asking a question you should never hold back possibly helpful information, as trivial as it may seem – your question is not just for you (see the [tour] and the [help]).

Comment: The opinion that a third-party has more control over the name than the author is nuts.

Comment: @Vadi Welcome to the colorful world of language. :) May you never need to speak about the *Windows 10 Enterprise Long-Term Servicing Branch Edition*. Wait, in your AU question, what are “specs”? oO

Comment: @Vadi we don't really care what they chose to call their stuff. Asus officially refers to themselves as ASUS. Nvidia as NVIDIA. We'll use whatever's convenient to write and easy to read. The idea that we should police our text to obey some company's naming decision is nuts.

Comment: It's not even that, it's policing what other people call it, as well! This frankly some very self-righteous thinking.

Comment: @Vadi eh? Where did that happen? The edit changed it to more readable text, this answer suggests that you use the ™ to indicate that the proper name is a trademark, and lastly you have exercised your right to rollback that edit. Who policed anything?

Comment: @Vadi I think the pronounciation is [ˈɛvəspeɪs] or [ˈɛvərspeɪs], or do you think the author forces us to capitalize that as well?

Comment: @Vadi how do you pronounce GIF?